# ¿Cómo puedo obtener solo elementos específicos de una lista de tipo Persona con stream?

Tags: java, filtro, stream

Quiero obtener solo elementos específicos de una lista de tipo Persona, esta lista contiene elementos como edad, estatura, color de ojos, nombre, appPaterno, appMaterno ... etc, todos los elementos tienen sus respectivos getters and Setters.

Para ser mas específico; tengo una lista llena con la consulta por `idPersona`, la cual quiero filtrar, y obtener solo los campos `edad`, `Nombre`, `appPaterno` y `appMaterno`(los cuales sean **distintos de vacio**), ignorando todos los demás campos del registro.

Tengo una idea de pasar la lista  a un `stream()` y de ahi filtrar los campos con las condiciones ya mencionadas, y devolver estos elementos como una lista de tipo `String`.

```
         public List<String>miMetodo(Integer id) {
            List<Persona> consulta = persistence.getMysql().createNamedQuery("Persona.obtenerPorId")
                .setParameter("id", id)
                .getResultList(); 
     //Solo quiero obtener id,edad(int), nombre,appPaterno,appMaterno(String) , descartanto inmediatamente los que sean nulos y vacios!
    //Mi idea! xD
List<String> consultaFiltro = consulta.stream()............
```

´´´
Persona es una entidad mapeada de una tabla guardada en mysql(solo pongo unos fragmentos de la entity)

```
    public class Persona implements Serializable{
    private Integer id;
    @Size(max = 256)
    @Column(name = "usuario")
    private String usuario;
    @Size(max = 256)
    @Column(name = "contrasena")
    private String contrasena;
    @Column(name = "activo")
    private Boolean activo;
    @Column(name = "fecha_registro")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date fechaRegistro;
    @Column(name = "id_elimino")
    private Integer idElimino;
    @Column(name = "id_municipio")
    private Integer idMunicipioAccedio;
    @Size(max = 256)
    @Column(name = "nombre")
    private String nombre;
    @Size(max = 256)
    @Column(name = "paterno")
    private String paterno;
    @Size(max = 256)
    @Column(name = "materno")
    private String materno;
    
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    public String getContrasena() {
        return contrasena;
    }

    public void setContrasena(String contrasena) {
        this.contrasena = contrasena;
    }

    public Boolean getActivo() {
        return activo;
    }

    public void setActivo(Boolean activo) {
        this.activo = activo;
    }

    public Date getFechaRegistro() {
        return fechaRegistro;
    }

    public void setFechaRegistro(Date fechaRegistro) {
        this.fechaRegistro = fechaRegistro;
    }

    public Integer getIdElimino() {
        return idElimino;
    }

    public void setIdElimino(Integer idElimino) {
        this.idElimino = idElimino;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getPaterno() {
        return paterno;
    }

    public void setPaterno(String paterno) {
        this.paterno = paterno;
    }

    public String getMaterno() {
        return materno;
    }

    public void setMaterno(String materno) {
        this.materno = materno;
    }
}
```

´´´

Comment: puedes agregar el código de tu clase persona para no regarla?

Comment: tu entidad no tiene edad! D:

Answer (score 0):

Yo primero me haría un método para filtrar si tienes campos vacíos:

```
private static boolean personaSinCamposVacios(Persona persona) {
    String nombre = persona.getNombre();
    String materno = persona.getMaterno();
    String paterno = persona.getPaterno();
    if (nombre == null || materno == null || paterno == null) {
        return false;
    }
    final boolean anyBlank = nombre.isBlank() || materno.isBlank() || paterno.isBlank();
    return !anyBlank;
}
```

Lo siguiente sería aplicarle ese filtro a tu stream:

```
consulta.stream()
            .filter(persona -> personaSinCamposVacios(persona))
```

Finalmente, para que obtengas solamente los campos que deseas como cadena ( que es el tipo que le pusiste a tu lista ), usa la función map, para convertir cada elemento en otra cosa.

Para eficientar un poco yo recomiendo usar la clase `StringBuilder` y de esa manera no dejar cadenas viviendo en la memoria por siempre que solo usaste para construir tu entidad.

```
String separador = " - ";
List<String> consultaFiltro = consulta.stream()
            .filter(persona -> personaSinCamposVacios(persona))
            .map(
                    persona
                    -> new StringBuilder(persona.getNombre())
                            .append(separador)
                            .append(persona.getPaterno())
                            .append(separador)
                            .append(persona.getMaterno())
                            .append(separador)
                            //.append(persona.getEdad())
                            .toString()
            )
```

Ahora tenemos que regresarlo de stream a lista, así que para ello usamos la clase Collectors que ya nos trae unos colectores <strike>bien ricolinos</strike> ya pre-programados para nosotros.

```
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

El código completo a mí me quedó así:

```
public class ElFiltrado {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Persona persona1 = new Persona();
        persona1.setNombre("Manuel");
        Persona persona2 = new Persona();
        persona2.setNombre("Rogaciano");
        persona2.setPaterno("El");
        persona2.setMaterno("Huapanguero");
        Persona persona3 = new Persona();
        persona3.setNombre("Oscar");
        persona3.setPaterno("Pérez");
        persona3.setMaterno("");
        Persona persona4 = new Persona();
        persona4.setNombre("Mary");
        persona4.setPaterno("Esmi");
        persona4.setMaterno("Amors");

        List<Persona> consulta = Arrays.asList(persona1, persona2, persona3, persona4);
        String separador = " - ";
        List<String> consultaFiltro = consulta.stream()
                .filter(persona -> personaSinCamposVacios(persona))
                .map(
                        persona
                        -> new StringBuilder(persona.getNombre())
                                .append(separador)
                                .append(persona.getPaterno())
                                .append(separador)
                                .append(persona.getMaterno())
                                .append(separador)
                                //.append(persona.getEdad())
                                .toString()
                )
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println("Filtrado:" + consultaFiltro);
    }

    private static boolean personaSinCamposVacios(Persona persona) {
        String nombre = persona.getNombre();
        String materno = persona.getMaterno();
        String paterno = persona.getPaterno();
        if (nombre == null || materno == null || paterno == null) {
            return false;
        }
        final boolean anyBlank = nombre.isBlank() || materno.isBlank() || paterno.isBlank();
        return !anyBlank;
    }

}
```

Y la salida es:

> Filtrado:[Rogaciano - El - Huapanguero - , Mary - Esmi - Amors - ]

Comment: @Rusion López  tengo una duda amigo ...                  
final boolean anyBlank = nombre.isBlank() || materno.isBlank() || paterno.isBlank();
        return !anyBlank;              Por lo que investigue .isBlank() es un metodo de la API Java 11 , y actualmente no puedo utilizar esta version de Java solo Java 1.8 , no se si fueras tan amable de explicarme como poder sustituirlo con java 1.8 o talvez este confundido, mil gracias y espero puedas ayudarme, aun no logro conseguir esto!

Comment: Entonces intenta hacer tu método inBlank que contemple la condición: `if(str != null && !str.trim().isEmpty())` y te dará los mismos resultados. En futuras ocasiones te recomiendo especificar la versión de Java que necesitas en tu pregunta.